# No Firefox plugin after installing Citrix receiver

Tags: firefox, citrix

I recently installed the Citrix client (amd64) on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded the appropriate file from citrix.com. The file I got was: icaclientWeb_13.4.0.10109380_amd64.deb . I've installed this before on other installations, Ubuntu and Fedora, without problems. Now however I have noticed that Firefox doesn't show the Citrix receiver plug-in that I was expecting there.

I've done several reinstalls but it won't appear. Any ideas or someone facing the same problem? Googling around I couldn't find any references to this problem or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, after trying some more it seems that the Citrix reciever is working, but that there is just no plugin in the plugin-list in Firefox visible. When I go to my company's Citrix login page I can login and start a session. Firefox will ask if I want to save the launch.ica file or if I want to open it using the "Citrix Reciever Engine". When choosing the latter it just brings me into a Citrix session. So, it works, even without the plugin... It seems therefore that there is no problem after all...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with newer FF versions (>=52) the NPAPI plugins are not anymore supported (FF is following the example of Microsoft Edge and of Google Chrome).

FF will simply not show them.

I am not able to launch the real receiver when going through Firefox as Citrix launches the HTML5 presentation of the published apps within the browser (no real pub apps feeling :-))

Hint: For Full Desktops the HTML5 thing is ok.